# Is it possible to include variable inside the binding string in ListView?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an array of objects which includes another array, which is used as ListView. I would like to display only this ListView which is currecntly selected in the dropdownbox. Is this possible?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding dgSamples[i].Test}" Width="645" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Where "i" is an idex of selected dropdownbox item.

Comment: No, it isn't. You'd need a multibinding/multivalue converter, if you really wanted to do that -- but see H.B.'s answer; your particular case is a much easier one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind via `ElementName` with `Path=SelectedItem.Test`.

(You can also bind the `SelectedItem` to a property and then bind to that instead.)